# Builder C++/Turbo C++ WebBrowser. How to access the received HTML code

Tags: c++builder, twebbrowser, borland-c++

I use Borland Turbo C++ (like Builder c++ but less components).

When i do Webbrowser1->Navigate(MyURL) I receive the demanded website properly.
In my case it is only a text website, not even html code. I can see it in the Webbrowser's window.

How do I access the received text to be able to manipulate it, count number of chars etc?
Best case would be if i can make it into an Ansistring.

I don't have any idea how to do it. Which class do I use or what type to try to convert to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First navigate to MyURL:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    WebBrowser1->Navigate(MyURL);
}
```

Put retrieve codes in **OnDocumentComplete** event:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::WebBrowser1DocumentComplete(TObject *Sender, LPDISPATCH pDisp,
          Variant *URL)
{
    Variant document = WebBrowser1->Document;
    Variant body = document.OlePropertyGet("body");
    Variant parentElement = body.OlePropertyGet("parentElement");
    AnsiString html = parentElement.OlePropertyGet("outerHTML");
    Memo1->Text = html; 
}
```

Or briefly:

```
Memo1->Text = Variant(WebBrowser1->Document).OlePropertyGet("body").OlePropertyGet("parentElement").OlePropertyGet("outerHTML");
```

Note that you can simply send http request and retrieve response text without TWebBrowser.

Comment: For better performance, you should use the DOM interfaces directly (`IHTMLDocument2`, `IHTMLElement`, etc) instead of going though `Variant`/`IDispatch`.